# Refresh parent windows form from child windows

Tags: c#, forms

I am having trouble trying to have parent windows form refreshed after closing the child windows form. Here's the code I have:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BusinessClient bc = new BusinessClient();
        bc.CompanyName = txtCompanyName.Text;
        bc.PointOfContact = txtPointOfContact.Text;
        bc.Address1 = txtAddressOne.Text;
        bc.Address2 = txtAddressTwo.Text;
        bc.City = txtCity.Text;
        bc.State = cbxState.Text;
        bc.Zip = txtZip.Text;
        bc.Phone = txtPhone.Text;
        bc.Email = txtEmail.Text;

        BusinessClientMgr bcMgr = new BusinessClientMgr();
        bcMgr.StoreNewBusinessClient(bc);

        AfterTheSave();

        AssignmentForm assignForm = new AssignmentForm();
        assignForm.Refresh();

        this.Close();
    }
```

What I'm trying to do here is to save the data and close the child windows form and have parent windows form refreshed by retrieving the new data to display. Am I missing something here? While I understand that the child windows form shouldn't control the parent. Come to think of it, a child is asking the parent to update the information.

Comment: Have you tried to search for a solution? This question has been answered thousand times.

Comment: `assignForm.Refresh()` has got nothing to do with the form data, this just redraws the form graphics.

Comment: @BastianThiede I have searched for solutions but none were found because all of them are related to ASP.NET which I was not looking for.

Comment: @Marc instead create a method and call it on `form_Load` event.

Comment: First - you create a new AssignmentForm - that's not the parent window. Second - it's not a great idea to introduce a dependency of the child from the parent. What do you want to achieve in the first place? Maybe your child window could provide an event, which the parent subscribes to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer by Aniruddha Varma is correct.

You have 2 forms: Parent and Child.

Into the parent, we are going to show the Child Form with this where you need:

```
Form2 child = new Form2();
child.Show(this); //We pass through the Parent instance to Child
```

And, also, we are going to declare a Public Method to edit whatever are your form controls like this:

```
public void SetText(string text)
{
    parentTextbox.Text = text;
}
```

After that, we pass into the Child Form. In this, we going to declare over the Form event "FormClosing" or into a button to close the form the following code:

```
 Form1 parent = (Form1) Owner;
 parent.SetText(childTextbox.Text);
```

With this, we are going to take back the Parent instance into the Child, and then callback the Method SetTex where we pass through the parameter our text. Looking back at the first form, we will have the Parent's textbox updated with text from Child's Form.

Comment: It's working - thank you for clarifying Aniruddha's post.

Answer (score 0):

Parent form code :

```
var child = new ChildForm();
child.Show(this);
```

Child form code :

```
var myParent = (MainForm)this.Owner;
myParent.ParentMethod();
```

---

`MainForm` is your parent form, and `ChildForm` is the new form you want to display.

Comment: Tried that - didn't work and didn't update the parent form with new data.

Comment: @Marc `ParentMethod` is a method on the parent form. You can call this method from the child form and pass an argument (say an `int`) and `ParentMethod` can update it's form.

Comment: @Marc What error(s) did it throw ? As Rakitić mentioned in the comment, the `Refresh` method is not related to the values in the form.

Comment: It didn't throw any error. It didn't just fire the event. Furthermore, I also discovered that in my original code above 'AfterTheSave();' was in the wrong place so I moved below the AssignmentForm because it clears all the field.