# WPF Update Parent Control Status from child Window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have got a status bar in Main Windows and I use User control as a child inside the main window. I just want to update TextBox in the status bar which is inside the Main windows.

```
 <Grid x:Name="grControls">             

 </Grid>    
 <StatusBar>
    <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="5">
        <TextBlock Name="NumberOfItemTextBox" >No:</TextBlock>
    </StatusBarItem>
 </StatusBar>

// CODE BEHIND I load Child windows into "grContorls"
        grControls.Children.Clear();
        var userCont = new PAMHeaderUC
        {
            ParentControl = this
        };
        grControls.Children.Add(userCont);
```

I just want to update NumberOfItemTextBox in child Usercontrol.

Comment: Check this, guess it's a double post: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050664/refresh-parent-windows-form-from-child-windows)!

Comment: Are you using MVVM pattern or just code behind?

Comment: I am using MVVM pattern

Answer (score 0):

These is code behind solution. If you are using MVVM it will be much cleaner.
From your usercontrol code behind, you can get your window, then you cast your window into your main window class that derives from Window and you got access to textBox

```
Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(userControlRefernce);
var yourInstanceOfWindow = (CastToYourNameOfClass)parentWindow;
yourInstanceOfWindow.NumberOfItemTextBox.Text = "someString";
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I am not sure i am doing right. In Usercontrol code behind i typed    Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this.Parent);
                   var yourInstanceOfWindow = (Main)parentWindow;
    yourInstanceOfWindow.NumberOfItemTextBox.Text = "someString";

Comment: Window.GetWindow(this), without the Parant, also it should be called after constructor of user control.